# GQCS gets notification, when WSAsend returns 0?

Tags: send, iocp

Although I have read a lot about WSAsend (msdn), I still need some clarifications.

Part of my code:

```
   int rc;
   rc=WSASend(Socket,....);

   if (rc==0) {....}
   else if ((rc == SOCKET_ERROR) && (WSA_IO_PENDING != (err = WSAGetLastError()))) 
          {
           printf("WSASend failed with error: %d Socket(%d) \n", err,(pTmp1->Socket));
           ....
          }
```

There is said in msdn that WSAsend operation may sometimes completes immediately returning zero (it never happened during my test server ). So if this happens, the `GetQueuedCompletionStatus` will get notification?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If any socket API call which initiates an overlapped operation which will generate a completion to an I/O completion port when completed returns 0 then a completion IS generated and posted to the IOCP. See [this Microsoft knowledge base article](http://support.microsoft.com/default.aspx?scid=kb;en-us;Q192800) for details. Thus you need no special handling for the non error return case.

Except...

If you are using [SetFileCompletionNotificationMode()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa365538%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) to set the the `FILE_SKIP_COMPLETION_PORT_ON_SUCCESS` mode. In which case a return value of 0 does NOT cause normal completion handling and you need to do your completion handling after the successful API call.