# I/O Completion Ports *LAST* called callback, or: where it's safe to cleanup things

Tags: windows, multithreading, sockets, atomic, iocp

I guess this argument is important and deserve some space here.

Let's consider the most common design of I/O Completion Ports in C/C++,
having a structure (or a class) which abstract the HANDLE, and some of its properties, like this:

```
class Stream 
{
    enum
    {
         Open = 1,
         Closed = 0
    };

    // Dtor
    virtual ~Stream() { if (m_read_packet != 0) delete_packet(m_read_packet); // the same for write packet }


    // Functions:
    bool read(...) { if (m_read_packet != 0) m_read_packet = allocate_packet(); ReadFile(m_handle ...); }
    bool write(...);
    bool close() { m_state = Closed; if (!CloseHandle(m_handle)) return false; else return true; }


    // Callbacks:
    virtual void onRead(...);
    virtual void onWrite(...);
    virtual void onEof();
    virtual void onClose();


    // Other stuff ....


    // Properties:
    HANDLE m_handle;
    int m_state;
    int m_pending_reads;
    int m_pending_writes;
    IoPacket * m_read_packet;
    IoPacket * m_write_packet;
};
```

This is pretty straightforward, you have this class which abstract an HANDLE, and the
IO Completion Port threads call its callbacks when i/o is completed. Plus, you can cache
and reuse the OVERLAPPED structures (derived by IoPacket) stored in those pointers.

You use this class by allocating a Stream object yourself, or just by let other classes to allocate
it, after a connection arrives (e.g. AcceptEx(), or a named pipe server). The Stream object will
automatically start to do i/o operation based on its callbacks implementation.

Now, in both cases you choose [1) allocate Stream yourself (client) or 2) from other objects (server)]
there will be a common problem: you don't know exactly *when* you can safely deallocate from memory the Stream object. And this is true even if you use atomic ref counters for IoPacket objects.

Let's see why: while doing i/o, the Stream object pointer would be contained in the IoPacket objects, which in turn are processed and used by other threads in the threadpool, which in turn uses that pointer to call the callbacks [onRead(), onWrite() and so on...]. You have also `m_pending_reads/writes' variables to see how many pending reads/writes there are. So, the Stream object pointer will be *shared accross threads.*

At this point, let's consider you don't need that connection anymore and you want to close and deallocate the related Stream object.

*how to do this safely?*

I mean, if you simply do:

```
stream->close();
delete stream;
```

you'll end up in some crashes because another thread may still be using the 'stream' pointer.
The safe way would be this:

```
stream->close();
while ((stream->m_pending_reads != 0) && (stream->m_pending_writes != 0));
delete stream;
```

But this is utterly inefficent since this blocks the path of executiong, block-waiting that other threads
finish their work with the 'stream' object. (And in addition I think I'll have add some volatile or barrier mechanism?)
The best way would be do that asynchronously, with another thread completing the *LAST* IoPacket for that Stream object, and call onClose() which in turn will be:

```
void onClose() { delete this; }
```

So my question is: how to recognize that I'm processing (in any thread) the *LAST* IoPacket (or OVERLAPPED) for the given handle, so after I could call safely the onClose() routine which deletes the Stream objects, which dtor in turn deletes the cached IoPackets, used for doing i/o stuff.

For now I use this method: if (for reading completions) `GetQueuedCompletionStatus()' returns ERROR_OPERATION_ABORTED [so it means CloseHandle(m_handle); has been called] OR bytes_read==0 [it means EOF] OR if (state!=Open) THEN it means that it was the last reading packet pending, then calling onClose(); after processing that. The write packets will ignore onClose().

I'm not sure that this is the correct method, because even if the reading packets are those which will be
always pending until an i/o event happens, it may happen that onClose() will be called by some thread scheduled *before* another thread which is willing to process a last write packet.

And what about those Stream objects derivatives (e.g. TcpClient) which also have other IoPackets? e.g. one for ConnectEx().

A possible solution would be to have AtomicInt m_total_pending_requests; <- and when this atomic integer reaches 0, the completion thread calls onClose();

But, is this last solution inefficent? Why do I have use atomic integers to do such a basic thing like closing a connection and deallocating its structures?

Maybe I'm totally in the wrong path with design for IOCPs with those Stream objects, but i guess this is a pretty common used design for abstracting HANDLEs, so I wanted to hear some opinion from IOCPs gurus.
Do I have to change everything, or this design of Stream objects could work pretty solid, safe, and most important, fast? I ask this because of the complexity came up for doing such a basic thing like close+free memory.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Reference counting solves the problem.

You simply increment a reference count when you do anything which will generate an IOCP completion and decrement it once you have finished processing the completion. Whilst there are operations outstanding your reference is > 1 and the handle object is valid. Once all operations complete your reference drops to 0 and the handle can delete itself.

I do the same for data buffers as my code allows for multiple concurrent send/recv operations to be in progress per connection and so storing overlapped structures in the handle itself isn't an option.

I have some code which demonstrates the above, you can download it from [here](http://www.serverframework.com/products---the-free-framework.html).

Comment: Thanks for sharing Len, I already gave a look at your code yesterday, great work! Yeah, I also thought to atomic counters as the *only* possible way to do that. Do you use an atomic counter for both OVERLAPPED structures (to count who's sharing them) and Stream (or Socket) structures (to count how many i/o op. are still pending)? Someone said that he does that without using any atomic, do you think it's possible? I puzzled over this for a while, and i couldn't be able to figure out how i can track pending i/o operations without an atomic counter for them...

Comment: My "per operation" (overlapped) structures are ref counted but they probably don't need to be unless you're writing a general purpose system where they can be kept alive outside of the I/O system. My "per connection" (socket) structures are ref counted and these effectively act as a 'per operation in progress on this connection' counter.

Comment: Yeah, I believe that the per-Socket structures *must* be atomically refcounted if you want to free them safely. I couldn't be able to figure out a way to do things safely when 1) a per-Socket structure is not atomically ref counted 2) you have more than 1 operation pending (e.g. 1 read and 1 write *both* pending) 3) you want to close and deallocate that connection's structures. In this scenario isn't impossible to safely free that per-Socket structure? I agree that OVERLAPPED doesn't need atomic counters, but per-Socket structures always need one, right?

Comment: I haven't yet worked out how NOT to ref count the per socket structure and I'd like to as I'd like to get rid of if possible...

Comment: Yeah that's very annoying. I guess a per-Socket atomic counter would work in this way: 1) You atomically increment the counter 2) Call the asynchronous API with a i/o request packet [e.g. ConnectEx(), ReadFile(), WriteFile(), AcceptEx() and so on] 3) Check the result: if that API returned error, you decrement the counter, if you got ERROR_IO_PENDING, you'll wait the completion callback will decrement it.

Comment: Pretty much. ERROR_IO_PENDING or ERROR_SUCCESS mean you will get a completion packet and so the ref will be decremented after processing , anything else means no completion packet... Remember to either deal with successes inline (if you've enabled "skip completion port on success" processing) or allow them to complete normally (if you havent).

Comment: Thanks, that's a very insightful advise. ERROR_SUCCESS means that ReadFile(), AcceptEx(), ConnectEx() and so on return TRUE and the i/o is done immediately, but Windows emulates an i/o completion even in such a case, just to make things easy. When in Vista or above we enable "skip completion on success" with SetFileCompletionNotificationModes(), that won't happen, so we have to _decrement_ the atomic counter when we skip completion on success is enabled *AND* those APIs returns TRUE (so the i/o is done immediately) and hence GetLastError() is ERROR_SUCCESS. Did I get it right?

Comment: @MarcoPagliaricci I think you are right, but better wait for Len's confirmation. In the meantime check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21075102/gqcs-gets-notification-when-wsasend-returns-0 and http://support.microsoft.com/default.aspx?scid=kb;en-us;Q192800 (tip 4)

Comment: maciekm, yes, I'm right ;) and the msft support link is the one that I base my understanding on... Marco, yes. When they return true a completion occurs normally (unless skip completion port processing is enabled in which case you have to handle it yourself) and personally I don't decrement on ERROR_SUCCESS when "Skip Completion Port" is enabled, I just call the handler code that the IOCP completion would call as that does the decrement for me.

Comment: Oh and beware recursive completions if your completion handler for, say, a read, issues another read or write. If you have enabled "skip completion on success" then these 'completions' could potentially result in recursion, depending on your design. I've recently designed that out of my system (see: http://www.serverframework.com/asynchronousevents/2013/03/reducing-context-switches-and-increasing-performance.html) but it bit me a few times early on :)